# Deleting the data in DLL

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll

After building of any C# project we will get a dll, and I need to place that dll in bin folder of sharepoint virtual directory(its a webpart..and I must place in bin folder not any other location). My question is when a user login he can edit the DLL in notepad and can delete the data and save. I would like to prevent him not to open in any editor (Notepad, Wordpad etc.). How can I do this? I gave the permissions to the folder as read still I am able to save it.

Comment: 'User login' - do you mean Windows user or web user? If it is Win user, you can set rights on folder/file. Web user cannot access these files, IIS will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Editing a dll in notepad and saving will corrupt it ( assuming anything allows you to do this ).

The solution is to only provide read permissions to the web site users on this folder - there is no reason for end users to have permissions on this, and it is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you secure your DLL in some way, no idea honestly how, this *potential user* can just delete your DLL and break your system. In IT there is a limit between what you should worry about and what you better leave there.

You can invent whatever security you want, but there will be *always* at least one client able to break all. So I would say in your concrete case, just don't worry about stuff like this and go ahead. Also, just as @Cat mentioned, editing a DLL with, let's say Notepad, will only corrupt it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think (guessing) perhaps you're getting mixed up between DLL and .dwp - the web part properties file which is XML.

This is the file you get if you "Export" a web part from the UI - it doesn't contain any code, its just xml text file with the properties.

There is no way that a user can modify a WebPart DLL via the SharePoint interface - they would need access to the server via Remote Desktop etc. and administrator permissions. Even with access - they are not going to be able to edit using Notepad - that would be like editing a video with a text editor!?

So how do you stop a user modifying the .dwp? One idea (assuming you've got a custom web part) is that instead of storing the web part properties in plain text key/value pairs in the XML you can store them as a single encrypted string.

If this is not what you mean can you please  clarify your question.